# How to find the wrong place of serialize string?

Tags: php, debugging, serialization

I have an string come from `serialize(array)` and store in mysql, as below:

```
a:146:{s:13:"interviewgame";s:6:"543.75";s:14:"100001X187game";N;s:19:"100001X187X3670game";s:5:"36.68";s:19:"100001X187X3667game";s:5:"42.42";s:19:"100001X187X3672game";s:5:"21.89";s:19:"100001X187X3671game";s:4:"9.31";s:19:"100001X187X3673game";s:4:"6.17";s:19:"100001X187X3674game";s:4:"9.24";s:19:"100001X187X3675game";s:4:"7.86";s:19:"100001X187X3676game";s:4:"4.83";s:19:"100001X187X3677game";s:4:"3.98";s:19:"100001X187X3678game";s:4:"4.12";s:19:"100001X187X3679game";s:4:"4.87";s:19:"100001X187X3680game";s:4:"4.72";s:19:"100001X187X3681game";s:4:"5.17";s:19:"100001X187X3682game";s:5:"16.18";s:19:"100001X187X3668game";s:4:"5.05";s:19:"100001X187X3669game";s:5:"57.61";s:19:"100001X187X3762game";s:6:"111.71";s:19:"100001X187X3775game";s:5:"58.79";s:19:"100001X187X3788game";s:5:"65.55";s:19:"100001X187X3801game";s:5:"45.24";s:14:"100001X186game";N;s:19:"100001X186X3661game";s:4:"4.58";s:19:"100001X186X3662game";s:4:"8.05";s:19:"100001X186X3663game";s:4:"4.97";s:19:"100001X186X3666game";s:4:"4.76";s:14:"100001X188game";N;s:19:"100001X188X3664game";N;s:19:"100001X188X3685game";N;s:19:"100001X188X3686game";N;s:19:"100001X188X3814game";N;s:19:"100001X188X3815game";N;s:19:"100001X188X3816game";N;s:19:"100001X188X3817game";N;s:19:"100001X188X3818game";N;s:19:"100001X188X3819game";N;s:19:"100001X188X3820game";N;s:19:"100001X188X3821game";N;s:19:"100001X188X3822game";N;s:19:"100001X188X3823game";N;s:19:"100001X188X3824game";N;s:19:"100001X188X3825game";N;s:19:"100001X188X3826game";N;s:19:"100001X188X3827game";N;s:19:"100001X188X3828game";N;s:14:"100001X189game";N;s:19:"100001X189X3665game";N;s:20:"100001X187X3670GG001";s:1:"0";s:15:"100001X187X3667";s:6:"??‰é??";s:20:"100001X187X3672GG001";s:1:"2";s:20:"100001X187X3671GG001";s:2:"-1";s:20:"100001X187X3673GG001";s:1:"1";s:20:"100001X187X3674GG001";s:2:"-1";s:20:"100001X187X3675GG001";s:2:"-3";s:20:"100001X187X3676GG001";s:2:"-3";s:20:"100001X187X3677GG001";s:1:"3";s:20:"100001X187X3678GG001";s:1:"3";s:20:"100001X187X3679GG001";s:1:"2";s:20:"100001X187X3680GG001";s:1:"0";s:20:"100001X187X3681GG001";s:2:"-1";s:20:"100001X187X3682GG001";s:1:"0";s:15:"100001X187X3668";s:0:"";s:20:"100001X187X3669GG001";s:1:"3";s:20:"100001X187X3669GG002";s:2:"-3";s:20:"100001X187X3669GG003";s:1:"3";s:20:"100001X187X3669GG004";s:2:"-3";s:20:"100001X187X3669GG005";s:1:"1";s:20:"100001X187X3669GG006";s:2:"-2";s:20:"100001X187X3669GG007";s:1:"3";s:20:"100001X187X3669GG008";s:1:"1";s:20:"100001X187X3669GG009";s:1:"2";s:20:"100001X187X3669SQ010";s:2:"-3";s:20:"100001X187X3669SQ011";s:1:"0";s:20:"100001X187X3669SQ012";s:2:"-2";s:20:"100001X187X3762GG001";s:2:"-2";s:20:"100001X187X3762GG002";s:2:"-2";s:20:"100001X187X3762GG003";s:2:"-2";s:20:"100001X187X3762GG004";s:1:"0";s:20:"100001X187X3762GG005";s:1:"1";s:20:"100001X187X3762GG006";s:1:"0";s:20:"100001X187X3762GG007";s:1:"0";s:20:"100001X187X3762GG008";s:2:"-1";s:20:"100001X187X3762GG009";s:1:"3";s:20:"100001X187X3762SQ010";s:1:"0";s:20:"100001X187X3762SQ011";s:1:"0";s:20:"100001X187X3762SQ012";s:1:"2";s:20:"100001X187X3775GG001";s:2:"-1";s:20:"100001X187X3775GG002";s:2:"-3";s:20:"100001X187X3775GG003";s:1:"2";s:20:"100001X187X3775GG004";s:1:"1";s:20:"100001X187X3775GG005";s:1:"1";s:20:"100001X187X3775GG006";s:2:"-2";s:20:"100001X187X3775GG007";s:2:"-1";s:20:"100001X187X3775GG008";s:2:"-2";s:20:"100001X187X3775GG009";s:1:"2";s:20:"100001X187X3775SQ010";s:1:"0";s:20:"100001X187X3775SQ011";s:1:"0";s:20:"100001X187X3775SQ012";s:1:"0";s:20:"100001X187X3788GG001";s:1:"0";s:20:"100001X187X3788GG002";s:1:"2";s:20:"100001X187X3788GG003";s:1:"2";s:20:"100001X187X3788GG004";s:1:"0";s:20:"100001X187X3788GG005";s:1:"2";s:20:"100001X187X3788GG006";s:1:"1";s:20:"100001X187X3788GG007";s:2:"-2";s:20:"100001X187X3788GG008";s:2:"-1";s:20:"100001X187X3788GG009";s:2:"-2";s:20:"100001X187X3788SQ010";s:1:"0";s:20:"100001X187X3788SQ011";s:1:"0";s:20:"100001X187X3788SQ012";s:1:"2";s:20:"100001X187X3801GG001";s:2:"-3";s:20:"100001X187X3801GG002";s:2:"-3";s:20:"100001X187X3801GG003";s:1:"2";s:20:"100001X187X3801GG004";s:1:"1";s:20:"100001X187X3801GG005";s:1:"3";s:20:"100001X187X3801GG006";s:1:"0";s:20:"100001X187X3801GG007";s:2:"-2";s:20:"100001X187X3801GG008";s:2:"-2";s:20:"100001X187X3801GG009";s:1:"2";s:20:"100001X187X3801SQ010";s:1:"3";s:20:"100001X187X3801SQ011";s:1:"0";s:20:"100001X187X3801SQ012";s:1:"1";s:15:"100001X186X3661";s:1:"M";s:15:"100001X186X3662";s:13:"39.0000000000";s:15:"100001X186X3663";s:2:"A3";s:15:"100001X186X3666";s:2:"A1";s:15:"100001X188X3664";s:1:"6";s:15:"100001X188X3685";s:2:"-6";s:15:"100001X188X3686";s:1:"6";s:15:"100001X188X3814";s:2:"12";s:15:"100001X188X3815";s:1:"3";s:15:"100001X188X3816";s:1:"9";s:15:"100001X188X3817";s:2:"-2";s:15:"100001X188X3818";s:1:"4";s:15:"100001X188X3819";s:2:"-1";s:15:"100001X188X3820";s:2:"-3";s:15:"100001X188X3821";s:1:"6";s:15:"100001X188X3822";s:1:"6";s:15:"100001X188X3823";s:2:"-2";s:15:"100001X188X3824";s:1:"1";s:15:"100001X188X3825";s:2:"-3";s:15:"100001X188X3826";s:2:"-9";s:15:"100001X188X3827";s:1:"8";s:15:"100001X188X3828";s:1:"3";s:15:"100001X189X3665";N;}
```

I try to `unserialize()` this string but get `false`.

Then, how to find or get some notice where is wrong?

Comment: You can use the website https://www.functions-online.com/unserialize.html to check your string ;)

Comment: s:15:"100001X187X3667";s:6:"??‰é??"; should be the problem.but I don't understand why

Comment: Have you tried removing those two values manually?

Comment: I can remove them ,but I don't understand how the messy code comes.